# How to create custom task in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have created custom task using VS 2015 Community and SSDT 2010. But, whenever I try to execute that task I am getting the below error
"Error: The task has failed to load. The contact information for this task is "Script Plus".

I am not able to find the solution for this problem.

Is there any way to debug SSIS custom task?

I have already referred following links,

http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.in/2013/06/create-your-own-custom-task.html
http://sqlserversolutions.blogspot.in/2010/05/create-custom-task-in-ssis.html

Please advise

Comment: Check the Event log on the server for any error messages. The message means that SSIS couldn't load the assembly, either because the task's installation failed, a dependency is missing, or you built the task on a 32-bit machine and tried to install it on a 64-bit server